# WebSocket unable to connect Tomcat server on google compute VM

Tags: websocket, tomcat8, java-websocket

I created a VM on Google Compute Engine and installed tomcat on it.
Following is the URL of examples that comes with tomcat.

http://35.245.146.222/examples/websocket/snake.xhtml

It always shows WebSocket connection closed.
Other examples that are not Websocket based runs perfectly.
Has anyone faced this issue?
This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Is it so much tough? its a bug of GCP while deploying tomcat service on VM on GCE, their server configuration wizards don’t know about it.